# An equivalent form of Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The standard form of Fatou's lemma states that if ${(\Omega, {\mathcal F}, \mu)}$ is a measure space, and ${f_1, f_2, \dots: \Omega \rightarrow [0,+\infty]}$ a sequence of unsigned measurable functions. Then

$\displaystyle \int_\Omega \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n\ d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\Omega f_n\ d\mu$.

An equivalent form of this lemma is that if one has$\displaystyle \int_\Omega f_n\ d\mu \leq M$
for some ${M}$ and all sufficiently large ${n}$, then one has $\displaystyle \int_\Omega \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n\ d\mu \leq M$ as well.

I would like to know more on how the second form implies the first, so far I got the following: Assume the second form. If we let $F_N$ be the non-decreasing sequence of functions given by $F_N := \inf_{n \geq N} f_n$, then by construction $F_N \leq f_N$ for all $N$ and so $\int_{\Omega} F_N\ d\mu \leq M$ for all sufficiently large $N$. By the second form and the monotone convergence theorem, we then have

$\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_N\ d\mu = \int_{\Omega} \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_N\ d\mu = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} F_N\ d\mu \leq \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_N\ d\mu \leq M$

Since $\int_{\Omega} \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} F_N\ d\mu = \int_{\Omega} \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n\ d\mu$, we get $\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n\ d\mu \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu \leq M$.

How does this help in establishing $\int_{\Omega} \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n\ d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu$? Or is there any ingredient missing?

Comment: Apply the second one to truncated $f_n$ and take limits

Comment: @Andrew It seems that the horizontally-truncated sequence $\min(f_n, m)$ does not necessarily has bounded mass for large $n$, can you elaborate further?

Comment: Think I get it now. The case where $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu$ is infinite is trivial, so we let $M = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu$ be finite. By monotonicity, $\int_{\Omega} F_N\ d\mu \leq \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu$ for all $n \geq N$, suggesting in particular that $\int_{\Omega} F_N\ d\mu \leq \inf_{n \geq N} \int_{\Omega} f_n\ d\mu \leq M$. Applying the second form to $F_N$ then gives the desired result.